# Can the size of a collection ( list ) be made less than 0 using reflection?

Tags: java, reflection, collections

Can we have the size of list less than 0. Can we make the size of the list or Map less than 0 using reflection.

Comment: Why don't you try? What makes you think we can't?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Pretending size to be less than zero probably is not a good idea as it violates an (implicit?) invariant ("size is the number of elements").

Comment: i have a code with such checks at lot of places. I wanted to see if there is any possibility as otherwise these checks dont make much sense.

Comment: In C you need that checks, otherwise you could write to invalid memeory. In java you simply would get an ArrayOutOfBoundsException. So java makes many chrecks for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. For example in the source code for `ArrayList`:

```
 private int size;
 //...
 public int size() {
     return size;
 }
```

Set `size` to some arbitrary value and the `size()` method will return it.

Note this very much depends on the implementation of the collection.

The OP asks: *I wanted to see if there is any possibility as otherwise these checks dont make much sense*

There is no point in checking that `size() < 0`. If you begin by assuming that someone has fiddled with properties of JDK classes using reflection then you might as well assume that they have set `Boolean.TRUE == false`...

Take a look at [this (very dirty) hack](http://jetcracker.wordpress.com/2012/04/29/the-magic-of-42/) that uses reflection to change the values in the integer cache to make `Integer.valueOf` return the wrong `int`.

Comment: Looks like my answer, has a similar reputtion, and has the name of my brother. ;-)

Comment: @AlexWien great minds think alike it would seem. Odd that we both went for `ArrayList`.

Comment: ArrayList is the most used Collection, at least for me. And it's probbyly simpler, that a hashtable. I have already looked at the src of ArrayList before, so for that I choosed it. Most probable this is valid for you too.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, with reflection you set the field named `size`.

E.g Look at source code of `ArrayList`.

```
private int size;
public int size() {
       return size;
}
```

But you don't have to care, too. Nobody will do that.